# Why can’t we map integers to real numbers to make statements about sequences of real numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, logic, solution-verification, induction

I have just recently learned about induction so please forgive me if this answer is painfully obvious.

As I learned it induction works by taking some number $a$ then we show that some statement $S$ holds, that is $S(a)$ is true.

Then we assume $S(x)$ holds and show that then $S(x+1)$ holds. Induction then proves $S(a), \dotsc, S(a+1), \dotsc$ all hold.

I learned that as real numbers can’t be listed, induction isn’t possible,

But what if we mapped integers to certain real numbers by making statement $S$ some function that outputs the real numbers that constitute our real numbers as a sequence couldn’t we make statements for not all real numbers but potentially for real numbers rounded to a certain unit that’s all that’s necessary for certain practical purposes, say because computers are limited to how many decimal places they can display, or some other device that’s only capable of accuracy up to a certain degree.

To summarise, given certain sequence of real numbers $a, b, c, \dotsc$ if we could construct a function that operates on the integers and $f(1) = a$, $f(2) = b$, etc., and we find some pattern to our sequence of real numbers then can we use induction on the integers forming the only variable part of the input of our function that produces our sequence of real numbers. Does induction allow us to prove something about a sequence of real numbers?

Comment: It is true that in "real life" we only need rational numbers , but that does not mean that induction will always work. Just an example : There is no proof by induction that there are infinite many prime numbers although many proofs are known.

Comment: Oh yeah I know that, I was just asking was induction possible sometimes if we use a transformation or function as I mentioned that outputs our sequence of real numbers that we suspect is say monotonic or something, could using induction on the input that we show always to produce the next real number in our sequence then prove that this property we found holds for the entire sequence?

Comment: There is no analogue to induction for the real numbers (transfinite induction still deals with countable cases!) , but you can "simulate" it as follows : If a statement is true for every real number in the interval $[0,1]$ and if we can prove that it is true for $x+1$ and $x-1$ whenever it is true for a real number $x$ , then we have proven that it is true for all real numbers. I do not think that we can do better.

Comment: But in the case of a sequence of real numbers , the situation is completely different since we might be able to establish links between $a_{n+1}$ and $a_n$ and have an $n$ over which induction might work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use induction to prove things about a sequence of real numbers. Although the sequence and the proposition would have to be pretty special, as you would have to be able to prove $S(a_{n+1})$ from $S(a_n)$.

The other point is that, if you're only going to prove things for a particular sequence of real numbers, you could just do regular induction on the index of the sequence. I.e. if your sequence was, say, $\{1+1/n\}$, instead of saying "for all reals, $x$, of the form $1+1/n$, $S(x)$", you could just say "for all $n$, $S(1+1/n)$".

Comment: Oh we haven't learned that yet, makes total sense though as you are still just taking steps of one integer in the denominator while other parts are constant. That sequence would have 2 as a limit, what if your sequence went something like 0.15, 1.12, 2.9 etc. Is there any simple way to design a sequence like you did that wouldn output the sequences

Comment: They are rather un-precise terms, but I think that once you've "designed" your sequence, you've pretty much "output-ed" it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use the Axiom of Choice (AC), which implies the [Well-ordering theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_theorem), you could. But why would you want to make a statement about an uncountably large sequence of real numbers using induction? I don't know what specific question you are attacking, but there could be a more direct route that doesn't require AC.

Comment: Even if you do resort to AC, you're gonna have a heck of a time with proving the induction step. I don't think any of the well orderings of the reals has a particularly nice "next element" function.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Good point, even naming/constructing them is realistically a no-go since the non-computable reals are uncountable. There isn't anything like a Java iterator "next" function for them AFAIK.

Comment: I was just wondering whatvthe general and absolute statement that induction can never be used. As I' currently studying induction at the undergraduate level I didn't know anything about non-computable reals. I was just trying to construct a counter-example to what I thoughtvwas an extremely broad statement with no mention ofvitvbeing proved, using the method.

Comment: @DaneMurray I wouldn't discourage you from trying to construct a counterexample since even if you fail it should be instructive. Feel free to post a follow up if you come up with something specific.

Comment: There is no "next number" in the real numbers, so induction in the usual sense (true for $x=0$ and if it holds for $x$ , then also for the "next $x$") cannot work.